How might communications on Mars work between bases if humans were there?
How might communications on Mars work between bases if humans were there? For example if there were humans on bases at the equator and the poles, would real time communication be possible? What infrastructure would need to be set up? How might existing infrastructure be used?

slightly relatred: Does the low conductivity of regolith limit lunar surface radio communication? and slightly more related (but different) Is it practical for HF skywave propagation to be utilized for space exploration robot telecommand when outside of microwave/mm wave range?

If you're imagining a Mars with multiple human bases across the surface, then you have to imagine fairly large amounts of material being transported from Earth and landed. In that case, it should be trivial to set up a communication satellite network around Mars for whatever base-to-base communication is needed; you bring the satellites from Earth and deploy them where they need to be. Ideally you'd put them at geostationary altitude, but there are other options like Molniya orbits if geostationary isn't an option for some reason.

Nitpick: "areostationary" is the correct word. The "geo" in "geostationary" literally means "Earth".

@JörgWMittag that fight is already being lost elsewhere; geology isn't losing its prefix when the rocks being studied aren't from Earth.

@JörgWMittag I'm aware, but I think being precious about terminology like that only makes it harder to communicate. Greek doesn't distinguish between Earth the planet and the concept of "the ground", so 'geostationary' could just as well mean 'stationary with respect to the ground' rather than being specific to Earth. We really don't have to invent a bunch of new names for orbital mechanics depending on what body we're orbiting.

Communication over large distances (e.g.: 60° of latitude) would likely need satellite relays.
Short wave transmission distance would be limited by the patchy Martian ionosphere, which is concentrated over the subsolar point:

Electron density for the Ls=0–30 season as a function of altitude and local time, for latitude 0 and longitude 0. https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jgre.20150
Medium wave transmission would be limited by line-of-sight.
Long wave transmission is potentially hampered by the low dielectric constant of the Mars regolith, which should not support ground waves.
Considering the massive infrastructure required for Mars habitation, a satellite relay system is a small addition.

you might also have an answer to Is it practical for HF skywave propagation to be utilized for space exploration robot telecommand when outside of microwave/mm wave range?
